# Synchronise css keyframe animation with jQuery setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I came across an issue. I've got a setInterval function of 7000 ms that does one small thing, and along with it a css3 keyframe animation set to 7s. Initially it runs perfectly in sync, but after several loops / time of animation they start to get out of sync more and more. so I am wondering is 7000 set in setInterval function same as 7s set in css3 keyframe animation, or are they different and therefore causing this dysinchranization over time?

Here is an example [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/48kx9/) (for some reason it behaves differently sometimes)

jQuery animation with setInterval:

```
function opacity() {
        $('#jQuery').animate({opacity: 0}, 100);
        $('#jQuery').animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
    }
    setInterval(opacity, 1000);
```

css keyframe animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes test {
  0%, 100%  {  opacity: 0; }
  10%, 90%  {  opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes test {
  0%, 100%   {  opacity: 0; }
  10%, 90%    {  opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes test {
  0%, 100%   { opacity: 0; }
  10%, 90%   {  opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes test {
  0%, 100%   { opacity: 0; }
  10%, 90%  { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: For that kind of thing, it is much better to use events like [`animationstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationstart).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon could you possibly go a bit more in depth on that on how it can benefit situation in my question? Link you provided is useful, but I didn't really get it.

Comment: Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/48kx9/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Think I got the idea, do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript can listen to the CSS animation and has different events:

- `animationiteration`
- `animationstart`
- `animationend`

In your case, since you have an infinite iteration, you are looking for `animationiteration` :

> ## animationiteration
>
> The animationend event is fired when an iteration of an animation ends. This event does not occur for animations with an animation-iteration-count of one.

*[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationiteration)*

Note that those events have their on browser prefixes :

```
W3C standard         |   Firefox              |   webkit                     |   Opera                 |   IE10
animationstart       |   animationstart       |   webkitAnimationStart       |   oanimationstart       |   MSAnimationStart
animationiteration   |   animationiteration   |   webkitAnimationIteration   |   oanimationiteration   |   MSAnimationIteration
animationend         |   animationend         |   webkitAnimationEnd         |   oanimationend         |   MSAnimationEnd
```

You can also add a [jQuery delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) if you want to wait a X number if MS before doing something.

The final code look like this :

```
$('#css').on('animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration oanimationiteration   MSAnimationIteration', function(){
        $('#jQuery').delay(250)//If you need any kind of delay
        .animate({opacity: 0}, 100)
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/48kx9/1/)